# How far can an athletic older woman jump down from a tree before she breaks her bones?

Tags: humans, medical

I have a main character who is in her late 50s, and she's an athletic woman with no health issues, or complications. She tends to climb trees a lot, and has a tendency to jump from the branches rather than climb all the way back down. At what point is it realistic, and at what point would her legs buckle and bones break?

She's worked on a farm all her life.

She is about 5ft 5inches tall. Petite but toned build.

I've seen through google that 15 meters is the farthest, but considering she is older, I'd imagine the height would be a bit less than that. She is older, after all. But no where near fragile.

Comment: I apologize, but this doesn't appear to be a worldbuilding question.  You appear to already have an answer and a good physical therapist can easily address the average difference from the answer due to age.  The question may be better suited to [Biology.SE](https://biology.stackexchange.com/) or [Health.SE](https://health.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: The only thing I would add to JBH's comment (which I fully support) is that you haven't factored in the high incidence of osteoporosis among women in that age group. Regular exercise and a farming life does not necessarily preclude you from getting brittle bones with age.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Cumulative Joint Injuries/Degradation is a real issue**

Humans have been known to fall up to 4 stories without injury, however it entirely depends upon what you are landing on, what position you are landing in, and health of the person falling. Women's biochemistry tends to pre-dispose them to at least mild osteoporosis and they already have a lower bone density than men in general. As she is older but athletic I would say that one might expect up to 2 stories without injury if landing on something soft like bushes or the forest floor leaf-bed directly on her feet and then conducting a tuck and roll upon impact.

The thing is, if she is doing this regularly she runs a very high risk for cumulative joint injuries. In the Marines we saw guys who had been in for 6 to 8 years suffering knee and hip joint issues like gout, arthritis, and cartilage and ligament damage just from jumping out of the 8 foot tall beds of 7-ton trucks on a regular basis. We are speaking about guys in peak physical condition who are in their mid to late 20's. Jumping from a height is not necessarily something that would cause harm to an athletic older woman, but I can tell you that if it was a very regular event she would be suffering knee, ankle, and hip issues by at least age 30. She has a lighter body weight and is not carrying a hundred pounds of gear like my grunts were but its still not a healthy lifestyle choice to be jumping out of trees or off ledges regularly. Unlike Anime or Kung-Fu movies human joints accumulate wear and tear over time from such activity.

Comment: Good point. She doesn't do it daily, but whenever the weather is nice enough, she climbs a certain tree (an oak) with her sister. I'd say when she has free time, and the weathers nice means that it isn't a daily thing, but it could occur every now and again, for a week or so at a time. Does that make sense?

Comment: Is there a way to delete this question?